# Quadratic equation with equal roots

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, quadratics

Okay, so I have a problem, which asks me to prove a condition ; i.e $(p^2=4q)$ based on the fact that the following quadratic equation has **equal roots** :

$$(1-q+\frac{p^2}{2})x^2+p(1+q)x+q(q-1)+\frac{p^2}{2}=0.$$

**My Try** Knowing the fact that a quadratic equation has equal roots if it's *Discriminant* is equal to $0$, I applied the same condition, but not only did my calculations become super complex, they also did not render the following proof.

*My question is, why am I not getting the answer from this condition? Anyways, there has to be a shorter method to this to solve **these kinds** of problems, please let me know how'd you solve them*.

Comment: I think you missed $x$ in some place.

Comment: The discriminant condition should work.  Wolfram Alpha says that the discriminant is equal to $-p^4 - p^2 q^2 + 6 p^2 q - p^2 + 4 q^3 - 8 q^2 + 4 q$ which has a root $q=p^2/4$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have $$p^2(1+q)^2-4\left(1-q+\frac{p^2}{2}\right)\left(q^2-q+\frac{p^2}{2}\right)=0$$ or
$$(p^2-4q)(p^2+q^2-2q+1)=0,$$
which gives $p^2=4q$ because  $p^2+(q-1)^2=0$ gives $p=0$ and $q=1$

and from  here $1-q+\frac{p^2}{2}=0$,  which is impossible.

Done!

Comment: @user38227 You are welcome!